# Android Studio IDE performance very slow

Tags: android-studio

With one project open the IDE runs smoothly but once I open two the IDE runs painfully slow. I'm suspecting a memory issue.

I'm running an i7 2015 mbp with 16gb of memory. How can I up the amount of resources android studio is allowed to use to the point where two projects open won't lag?

I've already updated `-xmx=2048 -XX:MaxPermSize=512m` via [Why Android Studio is slowing down when editing xml file or changing the design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27540695/why-android-studio-is-slowing-down-when-editing-xml-file-or-changing-the-design)

**studio.vmoptions**

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=225m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit version? Otherwise, 3GB of RAM is probably the limit (or even less).

Comment: There is only one version of Android Studio and it doesn't specify 32/64. It only says "Optional for accelerated emulator: Intel® processor with support for Intel® VT-x, Intel® EM64T (Intel® 64), and Execute Disable (XD) Bit functionality"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the properties the way I did is the first step.

The second step is not to touch Android Studio **AT ALL** until it is done processing. If you wait for all processes to complete (roughly 20 seconds) then it runs like it is supposed to.

---

It seems as though Android Studio's performance slows if you try using it when ANY processing is going on ie. if you wait for the first 20 seconds you're good to go but if it starts processing again for any other reason you have to wait until it's finished or you'll make the app lag quite badly for an indefinite period of time. This sounds like a bug that has nothing to do with memory available. In the meantime we'll just have to skirt around it...

** EDIT **

It seems as though the performance slowly crawls back if you lose it. Almost like a slow garbage collection. Restarting Android Studio when performance is poor is the only "fast track" I've found to getting around this bug.